# How to get the number of followers from twitter selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

Hello i was wondering how to get the number of followers of a person using selenium. I am not sure how to get the followers without having to use another and then go again as can be seen here but it still does not work

```
//this is not working
  follow_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.ProfileNav-item.ProfileNav-item--followers')
    followers = follow_box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a').find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.ProfileNav-value')
    follower_count = followers.get_attribute('data-count')
```

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = Chrome(options=options)


def get_tweet_data(article):
    user = article.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="User-Name"]').text.split('\n')

    name = user[0]
    username = user[1]
    postdate = user[-1]
    tweetText = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='tweetText']").text
    reply_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='reply']").text
    retweet_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='retweet']").text
    like_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='like']").text
    
    return name, username, postdate, tweetText, reply_count, retweet_count, like_count
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the desired element.